# Deduction Theorem Intuition

Tags: logic

I am using the deduction theorem from this site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem

Can you write the word implies as such for the deduction theorem 
(Δ∪{A}⊢B)⊢(Δ⊢A→B)? Also, I am confused because isn't {A} a set? I thought this {A} should be a [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent).

Comment: NO; the Deduction Th is a meta-theorem, i.e. a result about properties of the calculus and not a formula proved **in** the calculus.

Comment: The correct formulation of the DT is: if we have a *derivation* $\Delta \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$, then we can build a new *derivation*: $\Delta  \vdash A \to B$.

Comment: So it is okay that {A} is a set and that the formula is written the way I have it except the middle syntactic consequence should be ->?

Comment: Okay thank you for your help.  Just one more question. Should the middle syntactic consequence should be ->?

Comment: @W.G. I would stay away from $\rightarrow$ as well, since that is a formal logic symbol. Just stick to an 'if ... then ...' expression! Indeed, what you call the 'midlle syntactic consequence' is *NOT AT ALL* a *syntactic* consequence: it is a statement about the derivability of logic statements from other logic statements (where those logic statements may involve $\rightarrow$'s). So $\rightarrow$, $\vdash$, and a plain ;if ... then ..' are all different!

Comment: Can I ask why you wouldn't use that symbol just out of curiosity? I thought that if... then is the same thing as that symbol. Also, if you put your answer down in the bottom I am sure I would give it to you. You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol $\vdash$ express *derivability* in the calculus.

The syntax is:

> $Δ ⊢ φ$, where $Δ$ is a set of formulas: the set of assumptions (or premises) used in the derivation of the conclusion $\varphi$.

Thus it is correct to write $Δ \cup \{ A \}$.

The *Deduction Theorem is a *meta-theorem*, i.e. a result about properties of the calculus and not a formula proved in the calculus.

The correct formulation of the *Deduction Theorem* is:

> if we have a derivation $Δ ∪ \{ A \} ⊢ B$, then we can build a new derivation: $Δ ⊢ A→B$.

---

We have here two "levels": the level of the *calculus*, working with formulas written with the *connectives*. One of them is the *conditional*: $\to$.

Thus, $\to$ is a symbol of the language used in the calculus.

The second "level" is the meta-theory, where we have the relation of *derivability* between a set of *formulas* and a formula.

Thus, $\vdash$ is a symbol of the meta-language used to express the properties of the calculus.

The calculus is purely symbolical: it is made of "objects" called formulas, rules and sequences of formulas: derivations.

In the meta-theory we prove mathematical theorems about the calculus and its properties.

One of these theorems is the *DT*, expressing the fact that from an existing derivation (in the calculus) we can manufacture a new derivation.

The language of meta.theory is the usual math-English made of a mixture of symbols, like $\vdash$ and natural language; thus, there is no real advantage to use $\to$ in palce of "if..., then...".

But we can find [mathematical logic textbooks](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA98) where $\to$ is used as *connective* and $\Rightarrow$ is used in the meta-language to abbreviate "implies".

Comment: Well explained!!

Answer (score 1):

No, you really shouldn't write $(\Delta \cap \{ A \} \vdash B) \vdash (\Delta \vdash A \rightarrow B)$, because the $\vdash$ in $\Delta \cap \{ A \} \vdash B$ as well as in $\Delta \vdash A \rightarrow B$ is about the *derivability* of statements from other statements *relative* to some proof system (and so it would be best to use something like $\vdash_P$ where $P$ is the proof system you are considering), while the $\vdash$ you use in the middle is not at all that. So you really should just say that:

"If $\Delta \cap \{ A \} \vdash B$ then $\Delta \vdash A \rightarrow B$"

Likewise, I would not use $(\Delta \cap \{ A \} \vdash B) \rightarrow (\Delta \vdash A \rightarrow B)$ since $\rightarrow$ is a symbol used in a particular logic system that the derivability statements are about. Indeed, the $\rightarrow$ in $\Delta \vdash A \rightarrow B$ is part of the logical expression $A \rightarrow B$ that is claimed to be derivable from the set of formulas $\Delta$. But the $\rightarrow$ you would put between $(\Delta \cap \{ A \} \vdash B)$ and $\Delta \vdash A \rightarrow B$ is not at all combining two logic formulas, but rather two meta-logical statements about derivability.  So you really don't want to mix those up!

And yes, in logic we use $\rightarrow$ to try and capture 'if .. then ...' expressions, but the match is not perfect. The $\rightarrow$ is really just a mathematically defined truth-function, but the English conditional isn't always used in that way. Look up "Paradox of Material Implication", e.g: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication!

Finally, the $A$ is a statement/formula, not a sequent.