# Universal Quantifier Representation (Conditional Statement): Implication, Semantic Consequence, Syntactic Consequence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have seen $\forall x [P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)]$  written in multiple different forms from different authors. Which of the following are correct if any (as listed below)?

1. $\forall x [P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)]\equiv P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$
2. $\forall x [P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)]\equiv$ P(x), implies Q(x)
3. $\forall x [P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)]\equiv P(x) \models  Q(x)$
4. $\forall x [P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)]\equiv P(x) \vdash Q(x)$

Comment: This is basic stuff

Comment: @matboy: Complicated answers are welcomed.

Comment: No one. $\forall x \ [P(x) \to Q(x)]$ reads: "every $P$ is $Q$". See [Categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition).

Comment: The "syntactic consequence" relation: $P(x) \vdash Q(x)$ reads: "from (formula) $P(x)$, (the formula) $Q(x)$ is *derivable*". See [Proof calculus (or Proof system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_calculus).

Comment: The "semantic consequence" relation: $P(x) \vDash Q(x)$  reads: "(formula) $P(x)$ *logically implies* (the formula) $Q(x)$". See [Logical Consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  I was hoping you were going to answer my question when I posted this. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I was curious about that too. Thank you.

Comment: You can see the post [deduction theorem intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244043/deduction-theorem-intuition) for relation between $\vdash$ and $\to$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I know this question is unrelated, but could you rewrite the deduction theorem as this $(\Delta \cap \{ A \} \vdash B) \models (\Delta \vdash A\rightarrow B)$ then?

Comment: No; it must be $\Delta \cup \{ A \}$, because the set of premises is made of the formulas in $\Delta$ "plus" the formula $A$. $\Delta \cap \{ A \}$ can be at most $A$ (or maybe $\emptyset$).

Comment: The *Ded Th* reads: "if ..., then ..." at the meta-level: if we have a derivation (in the proof system) of $B$ from the set of premises $\Delta, A$, we have also (in the sense that we can produce) a derivation of $A \to B$ from $\Delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one.

$∀x [P(x)→Q(x)]$ reads: "every $P$ is $Q$". See [Categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition).

The "syntactic consequence" relation: $P(x)⊢Q(x)$ reads: "from (formula) $P(x)$, (the formula) $Q(x)$ is *derivable*". See [Proof calculus (or Proof system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_calculus).

The "semantic consequence" relation: $P(x)⊨Q(x)$ reads: "(formula) $P(x)$ *logically implies* (the formula) $Q(x)$". See [Logical Consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/).

$⇒$ is ambiguous; sometimes it is used for (logically) implies (i.e. semantic consequence), sometimes for the connective "if..., then..." (i.e. the [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional): →).

Answer (score 1):

As Mauro says: no one!  One reason for this that applies to all of them is that $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ is a *sentence*, as it is a formula without any free variables, but in all of the 4 cases you list you are dealing with free variables, i.e. formulas, but not sentences.

Of course, to really see that, you need to know what those different symbols mean, and Mauro explained all that, although one immediate clue should have been that in 1 through 4 there are no $\forall x$ being used.

So, maybe a more interesting question would have been: is the formula $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$ equivalent to any of 1 through 4? In which case 3 and 4 are still definitely not the same (see Mauro's answer), while for 1 and 2 they *could* be the same; by 'implies' we sometimes mean 'logically implies' (which would be like 3), but other times we say 'P implies Q' to mean 'if P then Q', in which case it would be the same as $P \rightarrow Q$. And, as Mauro says, the same is true for $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: Thank you as well. Your help is always appreciated!

Comment: @W.G. You're welcome! :)